# Maniging relations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-relations

I am working on an application and I have to create a model `product` which has many `pictures` and also a main `picture`. I want to model this situation through relations and not using an additional boolean field which can tell if one picture is the main picture or not. I think the solution is to use `has_one` and `has_many` relations in `product` that both link to `picture` but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need some way to distinguish your "main" picture from the other pictures. This can be done in a number of ways:

a separate database table, say, *main_pictures*

```rb
class Product
    has_many :pictures
    has_one :main_picture
end
```

or some other attribute on `Picture`. This can be a boolean or some other field. In the example, below, we'll use a boolean attribute named `primary` on the `pictures` table.

```rb
class Product
    has_many :pictures
    has_one :main_picture, -> { where(primary: true) }
end
```